# JDK1.6 + understand err file

Tags: java

I am not sure if someone will help me with the following problem but I will try

I installed the latest Java jdk version

And run some application

In the log error file ( from the application that I already run) 
I find the following

Can we understand from the following log file what the problem is?

```
 #
 # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
 #
 #  Internal Error (c1_Optimizer.cpp:271), pid=4224, tid=4004
 #  guarantee(x_compare_res != Constant::not_comparable) failed: incomparable   constants in IfOp
 #
 # JRE version: 6.0_25-b06
 # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
 # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
 #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
 #

      ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

 Current thread (0x02c98800):  JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon       [_thread_in_native, id=4004, stack(0x02ec0000,0x02f10000)]

 Stack: [0x02ec0000,0x02f10000],  sp=0x02f0f570,  free space=317k
 Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
 V  [jvm.dll+0x13363a]
 V  [jvm.dll+0x12e4fc]
 V  [jvm.dll+0x2052c2]
 V  [jvm.dll+0x205f96]
 V  [jvm.dll+0x1f0107]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell us your OS and if you show us the code you used to trigger this error.

Comment: I have WIN 32 bassed on XP , about the app sorry this ext app and I only want to install the ext app so I dont have the source cod-:(

Comment: see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553428/jvm-crashing-when-using-any-other-hibernate-inheritance-strategy-besides-single

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations, you've hit a bug in Java itself. There's not much you can do beyond reporting it on Oracle's forums and trying a different version.

Comment: how to find historic jdk version not  the latest/

Comment: you say that the err come only from JAVA JDK?

Comment: To be precise, it seems to be inside the JIT compiler inside the JRE.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this too and found a workaround: try to use the "server compiler", i.e. run java with "-server" argument.

Be aware that JRE on Windows doesn't contain the server compiler. Luckily, it is available in JDK.