# JVM crashing when using any other Hibernate inheritance strategy besides SINGLE_TABLE

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, single-table-inheritance, hibernate-annotations

Ok, this is probably a longshot but here goes.

In Java (JRE 1.6.0_26-b03) I have two classes, `SuperControl` and its subclass `SubControl`. They both need to be persistent objects and I'm using Hibernate Annotations to achieve this. I have approximately 210 classes that are being persisted correctly. Except one isn't.

My problem is that `SubControl` refuses to inherit in any way besides `SINGLE_TABLE`. When I say "refuses", I mean that **the entire JRE crashes**.

This is a bit problematic because I'd really prefer `SuperControl` to be a mapped superclass of `SubControl`. `SuperControl` can also be a persistent entity in its own right. The strange thing is that I have an exactly parallel hierarchy in my code elsewhere that works correctly.

This is what I want:

```
@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
public class SuperControl extends ItsSuperClass {
  // ...
}

@Entity
public class SubControl extends SuperControl {
  // ...
}
```

but it bombs out with the error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (c1_Optimizer.cpp:271), pid=5456, tid=1260
#  guarantee(x_compare_res != Constant::not_comparable) failed: incomparable constants in IfOp
#
# JRE version: 6.0_26-b03
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.1-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\eclipse\hs_err_pid5456.log
```

Without supplying any inheritance hint, Hibernate defaults to `SINGLE_TABLE` (which I can tell thanks to the creation of a `DTYPE` column). I can explicitly specify this without the JVM crashing.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class SuperControl extends ItsSuperClass {
  // ...
}

@Entity
public class SubControl extends SuperControl {
  // ...
}
```

The worst part is that if I remove the `SubControl` class ENTIRELY, or even just its mapping in the hibernate.cfg.xml file, the JVM **still** crashes. This leads me to believe that there's some kind of hidden linkage between `SuperControl` and `SubControl`. Maybe something cached in Eclipse or the like. I've restarted Eclipse, done several clean-and-builds, and even restarted my machine, and the problem's still there.

Any ideas? I've been working on this for hours and have gotten nowhere.

Thanks!

Comment: No misconception on your part should ever cause a JVM crash. There must be a bug in the JVM. Have you tried it on another machine, OS and/or JVM?

Comment: @JB: Not yet. Unfortunately I'm stuck with this architecture so whatever the culprit is I'll have to find a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Java 1.6.0_20, and check if that works. You have found a JVM bug, and going back 6 minor versions might be enought to get this running.

You are lucky in the way that this bug is reproducable, so create a minimal testcase and post it to the Oracle bug database.

Comment: Thanks. I went back a few versions (six, at your urging) and it runs just fine. In the morning I'll verify that nothing too important showed up between _21 and _26. And yes, I'll add this to the bug report once I get past my deadline.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a [bug 7042153](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7042153), aka [2210012](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=e7c91c5d1f2d0666265443e209ea?bug_id=2210012) reported in early May.

Note the workaround offered by one user: using the "-server" JVM option fixed it for them.

Comment: Also note the Evaluation: "_The problem occurs when we try to fold an If that has arguments of a condition that are constants of an object type and are not loaded._"  This suggests another possible workaround: force pre-loading of the problem class, if you can figure out what it is.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I tried running with `-server` but to no avail. Fortunately there aren't too many classes that could be the culprit, so maybe preloading will do the trick.

Comment: Don't forget all the classes that Hibernate creates on the fly at startup.